# LEFT JOIN with other param in ON Django ORM

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have the following models:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length = 255, default='example@example.com')
    authorized_credit = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    balance = models.IntegerField(default=0)


class Transaction(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    payment_amount = models.IntegerField(default=0) #can be 0 or have value
    exit_amount = models.IntegerField(default=0) #can be 0 or have value
    transaction_date = models.DateField()
```

I want to query for get all customer information and date of last payment.

I have this query in postgres that is correct, is just that i need:

```
 select e.*, max(l.transaction_date) as last_date_payment
 from app_customer as e
 left join app_transaction as l
 on e.id = l.customer_id and l.payment_amount != 0
 group by e.id
 order by e.id
```

But i need this query in django for an serializer. I try with that but return other query

```
In Python:
print(Customer.objects.filter(transaction__isnull=True).order_by('id').query)
>>> SELECT app_customer.id, app_customer.name, app_customer.email, app_customer.balance FROM app_customer 
LEFT OUTER JOIN app_transaction 
ON (app_customer.id = app_transaction.customer_id) 
WHERE app_transaction.id IS NULL 
ORDER BY app_customer.id ASC
```

**But that i need is this rows**

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUh52.png)

Comment: Hi,Welcome to Stack overflow. I will try to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you are working with a serializer or not you can reuse the same view/function for both the tasks.

> First to get the transaction detail for the current customer object you have you have to be aware of [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name).`related_name` have default values but you can mention something **unique** so that you remember.

Change your model:

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, related_name="transac_set",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

`related_names` are a way in django to create reverse relationship from `Customer` to `Transaction` this way you will be able to do `Customer cus.transac_set.all()` and it will fetch all the transaction of `cus` object.
Since you might have multiple customers to get transaction details for you can use [`select_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related) when querying this will hit the database least number of times and get all the data for you.

Create a function definition to get the data of all transaction of Customers:

```
def get_cus_transac(cus_id_list):
    #here cus_id_list is the list of ids you need to fetch
    cus_transac_list = Transaction.objects.select_related(customer).filter(id__in = cus_id_list)
    return cus_transac_list
```

For your purpose you need to use another way that is the reason you needed `related_name`, `prefetch_related()`.

Create a function definition to get the data of **latest** transaction of Customers: ***Warning: I was typing this answer before sleeping so there is no way the latest value of transaction is being fetched here.I will add it later but you can work on similar terms and get it done this way.

```
def get_latest_transac(cus_id_list):
    #here cus_id_list is the list of ids you need to fetch
    latest_transac_list = Customer.objects.filter(id__in = cus_id_list).prefetch_related('transac_set')
    return latest_transac_list
```

Now coming to serializer,you need to have 3 serializers (Actually you need 2 only but third one can serialize Customer data + latest transaction that you need) ...one for Transaction and another for customer then the 3rd Serializer  to combine them.

There might be some mistakes in code or i might have missed some details.As i have not checked it.I am assuming you know how to make serializers and views for the same.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use [subqueries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions):

```
transaction_subquery = Transaction.objects.filter(
    customer=OuterRef('pk'), payment_amount__gt=0,
).order_by('-transaction_date')

Customer.objects.annotate(
    last_date_payment=Subquery(
        transaction_subquery.values('transaction_date')[:1]
    )
)
```

This will get all customer data, and annotate with their last transaction date that has payment_amount as non-zero, in one query.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem:

> I want to query for get all customer information and date of last payment.

You can try use `order by` combine with `distinct`:

```py
Customer.objects.prefetch_related('transaction_set').values('id', 'name', 'email', 'authorized_credit', 'balance', 'transaction__transaction_date').order_by('-transaction__transaction_date').distinct('transaction__transaction_date')
```

Note:

> It only applies to PostgreSQL when `distinct` followed by parameters.
> Usage of `distinct`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#distinct